# Strange layout problem in IE6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, overlay, jquery-tools

[image]

URL: http://www.hkpete.com/test.html

jQuery 1.42
jQuery Tools 1.2.3 overlay

IE7 has this problem too (tested on ietester)

I can not find where the problems lie.

Thanks a lot.

```
<div id="dialog-content">
    <!--Login -->
    <div id="login" class="panel" style="display:none">
    Login..................
    </div>
    <!--Register -->
    <div id="register" class="panel" style="display:none">
    Register..................
    </div>
</div>

<!--Links-->
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="showDialog('#login','member');">Login</a>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="showDialog('#register','member');">Register</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ol;
var dialog=null;
function showDialog(panel,action){
      var each=each ? each : 0;
     function overlay(){
            if(panel){
                $("#dialog div.panel").hide();
                //show panel login,register,lostpw
                $(panel).show();
            }
            if(ol !== undefined && ol.isOpened()) {

                    $("#dialog").css("top", ( $(window).height() - $("#dialog").height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px"); 
                    $("#dialog").css("left", ( $(window).width() - $("#dialog").width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
            }

            //Overlay load          
            ol=$("#dialog").overlay({top:'center', left:'center', closeOnClick:false, api:true }).load();

            $("#dialog .close").click(function(){
               ol.close();
            }); 
     }


    overlay();
    //cur action
    dialog=action;

return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have Explorer 6 done anything correct?
You should share some source about what are you tring to do, than maybe we can help

Comment: IE6 is a unbelievable browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what this bug is: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/ienondisappearcontentbugPIE/index.htm.

The workarounds listed are:

> Work arounds One may 'release the
>   spell' in a number of ways:
>
> 1. temporarily switch the content's display property to
>      'block' and back to 'none'.
> 2. temporarily switch the content's position property from
>      'relative' to 'absolute' and back, or
>      vice versa.
> 3. temporarily switch the content's visibility property to
>      'hidden' and back. (But this only
>      works if the content is
>      positioned absolutely! The wonderful
>      world of IE...)

Go and have a look there for more information.

Answer (score 0):

thanks ,Yi Jiang.
the bug demo http://www.justarrangingbits.org/demo/2/

```
 //fix the bug
 if(panel){ 
           $("#dialog .panel").css({"display":"none","visibility":"hidden"});
           $(panel).css({"display":"block","visibility":"visible"});
 }
```